# swap on assembly

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

I wrote swap on assembly, but I'm not sure that my code is right, this is the code

```
swap:  mov r1, -(sp)   

   mov (sp) r1
   mov 2(sp) (sp)
   mov r1 2(sp)

   mov (sp)+, r1
   rts pc
```

swap receives pointer from stack

Comment: What architecture is it? PPC?

Comment: no, pdp-11, I'm working from simulator

Comment: [Not answer related]: Can you please specify the emulator.. I am looking for one :)

Comment: Note: there are missing commas in your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is sp a stackpointer? There is usually the command `ldw rA, 0(rB)` (0 is the offset and rB is the address you will load from, the actual data is now in rA). ldw loads a whole word into the memory, ldb loads a byte, `stw rA, 0(rB)` stores a word. `mov` usually copies one register to another.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    mov #1,-(sp)
    mov #2,-(sp)
    jsr pc,swap
    halt

swap:              
    mov 2(sp),-(sp)  ; a,b,ret -> a,b,ret,b
    mov 6(sp),4(sp)  ; a,b,ret,b -> a,a,ret,b
    mov (sp)+,4(sp)  ; a,a,ret,b -> b,a,ret
    rts pc
```

Better using another register for data stack